# Flink Filter function Testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-flink

I am trying to find the way to test RichFilter function just like RichMappFunction like present here : [RichMapFunction Testing is present here...](https://flink.apache.org/news/2020/02/07/a-guide-for-unit-testing-in-apache-flink.html)...Searched through internet and find nothing...Please help...

```
public class Person{
     public String name;
     public Int age;
}

public class OCRKafkaFilter extends RichFilterFunction<Person> {
   
    @Override
    public boolean filter(Person person) {
        return person.age>21;
    }
}
```

How can we write a test case for this rich filter function for stateful operators ...

Answer (score 0):

You can up a test harness for a filter function doing something like this:

```java
    private OCRKafkaFilter function;
    private OneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness<Person, Person> harness;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUpHarness() throws Exception {
        function = new OCRKafkaFilter();
        StreamFilter<Person> operator = new StreamFilter<>(function);
        harness = new OneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness<>(operator);
        harness.open();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example you gave, the RichFilterFunction isn't stateful. In that case you can write tests like this:

```java
public class FilterFunctionTest {

    @Test
    public void testFilter() {
        OCRKafkaFilter filter = new OCRKafkaFilter();
        Person person21 = new Person(21);
        Person person22 = new Person(22);

        assertEquals(false, filter.filter(person21));
        assertEquals(true, filter.filter(person22));
    }
}
```